# Passing arguments to Django social-auth Facebook login

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

My Django social-auth Facebook login works fine, using the default url `/login/facebook/`. I'm also able to do stuff with the new user by overriding the `update_user_details` method. But I would like to pass some more arguments to process in `update_user_details`. For instance, if I wanted to associate a model `Foo` with the user after it's been created, I should have liked to call the following url `/login/facebook/?foo_id=bar`, so that I can get back the `foo_id` in `update_user_details`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Set `SOCIAL_AUTH_FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ['foo_id']` in your settings, then you will be able to access `foo_id` in the session in your `update_user_details` by doing the usual `request.session['foo_id']`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I figured it out from the docs, but solved it another way.